# Open ListView Photos in Modal

Tags: react-native

I want to use `Modal` with `ListView` and open That in `renderRow(rowData){}` Area But Does not open.

That is okey in `render()` Area But I Got: a red Screen `Can't Find Variable: rowData`

**How Can I Fix That?**
[image: Photo]

**My Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, ListView, Image, Modal, Linking } from 'react-native';
import photosData from '../dataset/Photos'

var Dimensions = require('Dimensions')
var { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')

export default class MyListView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 })
        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(photosData),
            modalVisible: false,
        }
    }

    setModalVisible(visible) {
        this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
    }

    renderRow(rowData) {
        const img = rowData.image
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.containerCell}
                // onPress={() => Linking.openURL(img)}
                onPress={() => { this.setModalVisible(true) }}
            >
                <View>
                    <Image
                        //  resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain}
                        //  resizeMethod={"scale"}
                        style={{ width: width, height: 180, }}
                        source={{ uri: img }}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
                        <View
                            style={styles.imageUser}
                        >
                            <Image
                                style={styles.imageAvatar}
                                //   source={{ uri: rowData.user }}
                                source={require('../assets/icons/footer-avatar.png')}

                            />
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.footerTextContainer}>
                            <Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}           //I can see my photos in webview
                                onPress={() => Linking.openURL(img)}> 
                                Google
                            </Text>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>{rowData.food}</Text>
                            <Text style={[styles.text, styles.textTitle]}>{rowData.title}</Text>
                            <Text style={[styles.text, styles.textBy]}>By {rowData.by}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }
    render() {
        const img = rowData.image
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Modal
                    animationType={"slide"}
                    transparent={false}
                    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                    onRequestClose={() => { alert("Modal has been closed."), this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible) }}
                >
                    <View style={{ marginTop: 22 }}>
                        <View>
                            <Image
                                //  resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain}
                                //  resizeMethod={"scale"}
                                style={{ width: width, height: 180, }}
                                source={{ uri: img }}               // I can'ttttttttttt see my photos in Modal
                            />

                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
                                this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)
                            }}>
                                <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>

                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
                <ListView
                    style={styles.listContainer}
                    renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pasted your code, it seem you have minor syntax error of closing bracket but I hope it is just copy-paste mistake.

First thing, you should not place your your `Modal` in `renderRow` function, it can create problem sometimes with styling and data. You can place it in main `render()` method.

Add function call to your rendering method if data is available and set `this.setModalVisible(true)`.

Example:

```
render() {
    return(
        <View>
            {/* other code */}
            <Modal
                animationType={'slide'}
                transparent={false}
                visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                onRequestClose={() => { this.setModalVisible(false); } }
                >
                <View style={{ marginTop: 22 }}>
                    {(/*add some condition to check availability of data */)
                        ? this.renderRow() // rendering function 
                        : NULL}
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>
    );
}
```

**EDIT after OP changed question:**

Please find full code with my comment (not tested just added logic to work-around)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, ListView, Image, Modal, Linking } from 'react-native';
import photosData from '../dataset/Photos'

var Dimensions = require('Dimensions')
var { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')

export default class MyListView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 })
        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(photosData),
            modalVisible: false,
            currentImage: ''
        }
    }

    setModalVisible(visible, img) {
        this.setState({ modalVisible: visible, currentImage: img }); // set current image path to show it in modal
    }

    renderRow(rowData) {
        const img = rowData.image
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.containerCell}
                // onPress={() => Linking.openURL(img)}
                onPress={() => { this.setModalVisible(true, img) }} // pass image scr to function
            >
                <View>
                    <Image
                        //  resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain}
                        //  resizeMethod={"scale"}
                        style={{ width: width, height: 180, }}
                        source={{ uri: img }}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
                        <View
                            style={styles.imageUser}
                        >
                            <Image
                                style={styles.imageAvatar}
                                //   source={{ uri: rowData.user }}
                                source={require('../assets/icons/footer-avatar.png')}

                            />
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.footerTextContainer}>
                            <Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}           //I can see my photos in webview
                                onPress={() => Linking.openURL(img)}> 
                                Google
                            </Text>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>{rowData.food}</Text>
                            <Text style={[styles.text, styles.textTitle]}>{rowData.title}</Text>
                            <Text style={[styles.text, styles.textBy]}>By {rowData.by}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }
    render() {
        // const img = rowData.image
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Modal
                    animationType={"slide"}
                    transparent={false}
                    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                    onRequestClose={() => { alert("Modal has been closed."), this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible) }}
                >
                    <View style={{ marginTop: 22 }}>
                        <View>
                            <Image
                                //  resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain}
                                //  resizeMethod={"scale"}
                                style={{ width: width, height: 180, }}
                                source={{ uri: this.state.currentImage }}               // use currentImage scr to show on clicking list item
                            />

                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
                                this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)
                            }}>
                                <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>

                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
                <ListView
                    style={styles.listContainer}
                    renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @jigar-shah I Couldn't understand very well and I Got syntax error, I updated my question with a photo, I want to get each rowData.image in modal, and I Should use ``` <Image style={{ width: width, height: 180, }} source={{ uri: img }} />``` in render Area bot I got error and i described in photo, Can you please fix my code? , I updated my Code Again, Now I got: `Can't find variable: rowData` How Can I Fix That

Comment: your current code have `const img = rowData.image` in render(), it can not be accessed there. So you are getting `can't find variable : rowData`

Comment: Dear @jigar-shah How Can I Solve That? , I need to open each photo in modal View, in web View is ok because that is in `renderRow(rowData) {`

Comment: You can create one array that store src of images in `renderRow()` where you can access `rowData.image`, then you can use Modal to show that images in Modal using some event triggering modal visible true

Comment: Thank you, I'm New in programming, Then I should search and work on array. maybe that is defficult for me.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can get that url while you are clicking on the list item in `renderRow()` . I have added `currentImage` state variable to set current clicked list item's src.

Comment: Solved Dear @jigar-shah , You Are Awsome, Thank you Very much, I appreciate it.